# Struts form values are repeated on form submission

Tags: java, jquery, forms, struts2

I have a Struts2 web application where I have components like textbox, textarea, dropdown and table. When I enter or choose the values in the form and submit, the values are repeated with comma separation. For ex, the dropdown has values like `New and Used`. If I choose **New** and then submit, the variable in java, is assigned with the values like **New, New**. The same is happening for TextArea as well. No issues with Textbox.

Please let me know what I am missing. Sample JSP code below:

**Code:**

```
<s:iterator value="reqBean.newAllocList" var="materialPlanningItem" status="matStat">
  <tr>
    <td><s:select name="reqBean.newAllocList[%{#matStat.index}].type" cssClass="actionType" list="{'','New','Used'}" /></td>
    <td><s:textarea name="reqBean.newAllocList[%{#matStat.index}].allocationComments" cssClass="form-control" rows="3"></s:textarea>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

**EDIT**

Attached the JS code to submit the form:

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){
    startCfaPB(); -- This method is to load the progress bar
    document.forms[0].action = "submitRequestsAllocation.action";
    document.forms[0].submit();
});
```

Comment: I think one is for option value and one is for option text.Your list should contain key and value

Comment: You must have some duplicate tag somewhere. Please post the request data taken from developer tools, firebug or whatever, and ensure you haven't duplicate tags in the same form

Comment: show how you submit